# Deployment of Elasticsearch on Azure from the scratch

Tags: azure, elasticsearch, bigdata

I am beginner in elastic search.I have implemented elastic search for single node with NEST Client in my C# Web Application successfully.Now I want to scale my data horizontally and want to deploy this application on Azure cloud storage.so if any article or documentation(step by step) is available for how to effectively deploy Elasticsearch with proper configuration on Azure with multi node then inform me.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Elastic's Azure Marketplace offering](https://azuremarketplace.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/apps/elastic.elasticsearch). Within a few screens and minutes, you'll have a cluster deployed on Azure.

If you need more control over the deployed cluster such as

- number and size of disks to attach to each data node
- install Azure repository plugin for snapshot/restore
- Java heap size for each node

take a look at the [ARM template on GitHub](https://github.com/elastic/azure-marketplace). This is the same underlying template that powers the Marketplace offering, but deploying directly provides more features than are exposed in the Marketplace UI.